# Conectar Proyecto Laravel 8 a Advantage Database

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, odbc, sap

Dispongo de unas bases de datos en Advantage DataBase y necesito conectarlas a un nuevo proyecto hecho en Laravel 8, me he descargado el Driver en Windows 64bit, he configurado una conexión ODBC pero no consigo conectar desde Laravel me indica el siguiente error:

InvalidArgumentException
Unsupported driver [Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC]

En el archivo database.php de la carpeta config tengo la siguiente conexion:

```
'adsODBC' => [
            'driver' => 'Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC',
            'DataDirectory' => '/IP/Ruta de carpetas/Nombre del archivo .add',
            'UID' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'PWD' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'Charset' => 'ANSI',
            'DefaultType' => 'FoxPro',
            'Rows' => 'False',
            'AdvantageLocking' => 'ON',
            'Locking' => 'Record',
            'MemoBlockSize' => '64',
            'MaxTableCloseCache' => '25',
            'ServerTypes' => '2',
            'TrimTrailingSpaces' => 'False',
            'CommType' => 'TCP_IP',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE')
        ]
```

Comment: Hola, lo lograste solucionar ? , en caso de ser positivo , cual fue la solución?,  estamos teniendo el mismo problema, pero intentando conectarnos a sap hana , siempre detecta a MYSQL como la conexión por defecto.